# Is there a way to print directly to printer from Java by bypassing Windows spooler?

Tags: java, printing, thermal-printer, spooler

Is there a way to print directly to usb printer by bypassing Windows spooler?
I need a get an immediate feedback is printing job was succeeded or not. When I send it to spooler and it stuck, I have no any indication did it success or not.

Update: now, when I try to print directly (in printer properties check check-box, Print directly to the printer) I get the following error:
[image]

Reboot doesn't help :(
I also tried download reference example from Oracle site http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/examples/HelloWorldPrinter.java
same error, is there any workaround, settings to overcome this issue?

Thank you very much!

Update2:  We use printer Citizen CT-S801

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by replacing 801 driver with old one from 310 series, after this 'patch' direct printing works flawlessly. Most angered me in this story Citizen's support. They even haven't checked my problem, just said that problem in my Java application and they won't debug program for me.